# What maintenance changes do I have to make to my 09 Acura TSX when it reaches 100k miles?

Tags: maintenance, acura

My Acura TSX is reaching the 100k miles range soon and I'm looking to get advice on maintenance changes. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I received this information from [this site](https://www.driverside.com/service-schedule/detailview/acura-tsx-2009-23448-30947-56204&mileage=100000). It is the 100,000 mile maintenance service specification for the 2009 Acura TSX.

```
Action:                 Description
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Rotate Tires
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Replace engine oil and filter
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect windshield wiper and washer systems and fluids levels
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect suspension components
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect steering linkage
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect power steering fluid level
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect half shaft dust boots
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect exhaust system
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect engine accessory drive belt
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect coolant recovery reservoir
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect clutch operation
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect brake fluid level
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect automatic/manual transmission fluid
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Inspect air cleaner/element
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Check turn signals and hazard warning lights
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Check shocks and struts
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Check radiator, coolers, heater, and A/C hoses
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Check battery, exterior lamps, and horn operation
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Replace spark plugs
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Replace PCV valve
Inspect/Adjust/Change   Replace coolant
```